# CreateThread() does not work

Tags: c++, c++11, winapi

I am trying to create a thread using the winapi's CreateThread() function, but it doesnt work. No errors at all

```
void Inc::init() {
    DWORD id;
    HANDLE hnd = CreateThread(NULL,0,asd,this,0,&id);
}
DWORD Inc::asd(LPVOID lparam) {
    Inc* g = (Inc*)lparam;
    printf("asd");
}
```

asd() doesn't get executed at all

Comment: Are you *sure* it's not running? Perhaps it's a buffering issue, since the string you print will not be flushed. Try adding a trailing newline to the string you print. And perhaps learn how to use a debugger to put a *breakpoint* in the thread function to see it it's executed. You should probably check what `CreateThread` returns as well.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please read how to create a [MCVE] and [ask].

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Windows never uses line buffering, so adding a newline won't make any difference.  (Well, maybe if he's using a third-party C runtime, but that's unlikely.)

Comment: If this is a 32-bit application, the thread function must be declared `WINAPI`.

Comment: I guess you ignored the errors with a cast that we can't see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't post any minimal compiling code we can help you debug, so, everything I'm about to say are guesses based on other questions I've seen on this topic:

1. make sure `asd` is declared `static`, `CreateThread` is a C function and knows nothing about class methods
2. make sure `asd` is declared `__stdcall`, having wrong calling convention can cause weird and unexpected results.
3. make sure `this` is not destroyed until your thread finishes running.
4. make sure your program doesn't finish **before** the thread finishes running. you don't expect to see to output if the program exits before the thread gets a change to print something, right? store the thread handle somewhere, and use `WaitForSingleObject` to make sure the thread work is done.
5. `asd` doesn't return any `DWORD` value. make sure to return some return code.

General notes:

1. don't use C-casts, use C++ cast like `static_cast`
2. the standard library already has a thread object: `std::thread`. consider using that instead.
3. Like any system call, you **must** check the result of any system call. if the returned handle is null, you should check the value of the last error with `GetLastError`.